# How to change XAML value using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a style file for Styles in WPF XAML with name Brushes.xaml which stores all colors for the WPF.

Code Here:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">    
    <Color x:Key="DefaultColor">SteelBlue</Color>
    <Color x:Key="LightDefaultColor">LightSteelBlue</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I want to change the value of DefaultColor using C# code.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There is almost certainly a better solution than changing file with styles at runtime.

Comment: I have various themes for my application. So then how to change the FileName.. Since i am using Brushes.xaml in various other XAML files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the DynamicResource extension instead of the StaticResource extension on all references to keys that can change at runtime.

Then you can use code like the following to change the value.

```
Application.Current.Resources["Default Color"] = System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red;
```

This can be done per object to...

```
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Resources["Default Color"] = System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red;
    PART_DynamicButton.Resources["Default Color"] = System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red;
}
```

This is higher performance than clearing your entire merged resource dictionary and adding a new one if you only need to modify a few values.

Just remember that DynamicResource extension only works on DependencyProperties and Freezable objects instantiated in Xaml are usually frozen which prevents modifing their DependencyProperties. So don't try to change the color of a SolidColorBrush if the brush was instaniated in xaml.

Here is a workaround

```
<! -- Xaml -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="App_Page_Background" Color="White"/>

<Page Background="{DynamicResource App_Page_Background}"/>

// C# code
Application.Current.Resources["App_Page_Background"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the XAML contents you should create one XAML file for each theme. 
Then you can change the theme at runtime like this:

```
ResourceDictionary skin = new ResourceDictionary();
skin.Source = new Uri(@"" + themeName + ".xaml", UriKind.Relative);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(skin);
```